# Why do the ruby docs for versions > 1.8 not include Hash#sort

Tags: ruby

Hash#sort actually exists in ruby version 2.3.0, however it is not listed in the docs at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html. It seems to have disappeared from the ruby docs after 1.8.0. What is the reason that the method Hash#sort exists but is not included in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hash is an Enumerable. `sort` is listed under Enumerable.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort

Comment: Hash *includes* Enumerable and `sort` is *defined by* Enumerable.

Comment: Hash, like many Ruby classes, inherits methods from a variety of sources, Enumerable included. This may come as a surprise to those not familiar with how Ruby works.

Comment: @Jordan Whatever. Feel free to edit. I'm not interested in the style police, so word it however you like. To me, it's a question not about Ruby, anyway, but about how to read the docs web page.

Comment: @Jordan: `{}.is_a?(Enumerable) # => true`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 

Comment: @matt I agree it is about reading the docs page correctly. Now I see the section "included modules" which contains Enumerable. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyD: To answer the *literal* question from your question: "What is the reason that the method `Hash#sort` exists but is not included in the docs?" – Your premise is wrong, the method `Hash#sort` *doesn't* exist: `{}.method(:sort).owner #=> Enumerable`.